# PDFBox - PDFComboBox not printing complete value String of selected drop down value

Tags: java, combobox, pdfbox

I am new to **PDFBox**, would really appreciate your help with the below,

**I am trying to read a pdf file and store the values in database**. There is an issue reading entire String of selected value in the drop-down using **PDFCombobox** which is selected in the form.

Below is my code :

`main` method :

```
File f = new File("filename.pdf");
pdf = Loader.loadPDF(f);
PdfboxMain exporter = new PdfboxMain();
exporter.printFields(pdf);
```

`printFields(pdf)` method :

```
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();

for (PDField field : fields) {
    if  (field.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDComboBox")) {
        // This line only prints partial String of selected value
        System.out.println(field.getValueAsString());
    }
}
```

In the above scenario, `field.getvalueAsString()` is only returning partial String of the selected value, (i.e.,) actual value String is "Modification or Addition to Existing Project", however the returned value is only "Modify".

However, if I use the below line, it prints all the available values in the drop-down (displays Entire String instead of half).

```
List<String> pdbox = ((PDChoice) field).getOptionsDisplayValues();
```

But my requirement is to get only the selected value as complete string.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please share your PDF. Also (unrelated) don't use `acroForm.getFields()`, use `acroForm.getFieldTree()`.